# Links in view files that are called through different named routes

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5.8

Our team is trying to convert an old multitenant architecture over to Laravel and having some difficulty staying DRY in our routes/views.

Our account section contains multiple page views: an account dashboard, edit profile, payment methods, registrations, etc. However, we provide multiple stand-alone websites for a client, and there are multiple URL structures for the user to access their account:

In addition to the standard...

- https://clientone.ourdomain.com/account/

...they can also access their account via different standalone websites:

- https://clientone.ourdomain.com/event-app-one/account/
- https://clientone.ourdomain.com/event-app-two/account/

All of those URLs above give them the exact same information, but with a different layout/theme applied for each standalone website. Right now the routes I set up for those above look like this:

```
// #### CLIENT ONE - ROOT
Route::domain('{subdomain}.ourdomain.com')->group(function() {
  Route::middleware(['setTheme:clientone-account-theme'])->group(function() {
    Route::get('/', 'ClientController@index')->name('index');
    Route::prefix('account')->group(function() {
      Route::get('/', 'AccountController@index')->name('clientone.account.show');
      Route::get('/edit', 'AccountController@edit')->name('clientone.account.edit');
      ...
    });
  });
  // #### CLIENT ONE - EVENT APP ONE
  Route::prefix('event-app-one')->group(function() {
    Route::middleware(['setTheme:clientone-eventapp-one-theme'])->group(function() {
      Route::get('/', 'EventAppController@index')->name('clientone.eventapp.one.index');
      ...
      Route::prefix('account')->group(function() {
        Route::get('/', 'AccountController@index')->name('clientone.eventapp.one.account.show');
        Route::get('/edit', 'AccountController@edit')->name('clientone.eventapp.one.account.edit');
        ...
      });
    });
  });
  // #### CLIENT ONE - EVENT APP TWO
  Route::prefix('event-app-2')->group(function() {
    Route::middleware(['setTheme:clientone-eventapp-two-theme'])->group(function() {
      Route::get('/', 'EventAppController@index')->name('clientone.eventapp.two.index');
      ...
      Route::prefix('account')->group(function() {
        Route::get('/', 'AccountController@index')->name('clientone.eventapp.two.account.show');
        Route::get('/edit', 'AccountController@edit')->name('clientone.eventapp.two.account.edit');
        ...
    });
  });
});
```

Those routes all currently work. We don't like including the client or app name in all of our route names because they get rather long and can't be reused, but if we take those out we found out our route URLs will override each other.

However, if we do it this way, our account views that we share across all these URLs can't use named route links for href because we don't know which one to use. For example, we can't do this in blade...

```
<a href="{{ route($subdomain . '.account.edit', ['subdomain' => $subdomain]) }}">Edit Profile</a>
```

...because, while that will work while at clientone.ourdomain.com/account/, it won't work while at clientone.ourdomain.com/event-app-one/account/.

Should I just not use route names for links in our views and use a relative link instead? Or am I going about my route naming all wrong? The only other thing I can think of is to copy all the view files and have one version for .com/account/ and another for .com/all-event-apps/account/ and just use a different set of route names for each. Feels wrong to duplicate essentially the same functionality in those views though.

Comment: I think adding parameter to route and making it dynamic will solve your problem , like route::get(myroot/{event-template}/account) and use event-template in your logic.

Comment: you can differentiate views like `return view('dashboard'.$event_template,$this->data[$event_template]); `

Answer (score 0):

You can use a parameter for the prefix so you are not repeating the same exact routes and creating new names for them. You can then generate routes based on those route names.

You can set defaults for parameters for the `UrlGenerator` to help deal with this.

I would add a middleware to your group that checks the prefix then will assign that as a default parameter on the UrlGenerator:

```
// instead of app-one, app-two, etc etc
Route::prefix('{app}')->middleware('handleapp')...

// handleapp middleware

Url::defaults(['app' => $request->route()->parameter('app')]);

$request->route()->forgetParameter('app'); // if you dont want this passed into controller methods

// where you need to generate a route
route('eventapp.account.edit'); // {app} is handled by the default we set so doesn't have to be passed
```

I would also have a middleware that will add the default parameter for `subdomain` as well so you don't have to pass that yourself everywhere.

Basically it all becomes dynamic and based on the current request you can have defaults setup for all these parameters so you don't have to pass them into the route helpers yourself everywhere you need a URL from a route name.

This is just the basic idea in use.